# Where to find SafeMath pragma solidity ^0.6.6?

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, import, safemath

While trying to use `SafeMath` to compute the modulo of a `uint256` like shown in this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqZWariqh5s (without SafeMath) I'm having some trouble finding a pragma solidity 0.6.6 version of the SafeMath contract.

If I simply use the `@openzeppelin` command it defaults to `pragma solidity 0.8.0` which is incompatible with the remainder of my code. Hence, I was wondering: where I can find a working `SafeMath.sol` file using `pragma solidity 0.6.6`?

Comment: For anyone seeing this in 2022 and beyond: you don't need `SafeMath` in Solidity v0.8 and above anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get that on openzepplins github. Just navigate to Github then Openzeeplin-contracts. Go to the branches and check a lower branch.

```
import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v3.3/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';
```